# Display two Image views horizontally

Tags: android

I have the following requirements.

1. I am displaying two blank images(ImageView) in landscape mode.
2. Based on some logic, I need to put two TextViews on each image. For this reason, I am using a class which extends BaseAdapter.

I have already created the same using Gallery for multiple images (images more than 2), but the requirement is that for two images, it should not be scrollable & also there will not be any centre image, as is the case when I am using Gallery where an Image occupies the centre portion of the screen.

The two images needs to be spaced e.g., Image 1 should have 20dip from left margin whereas Image2 should have 20dip from right margin.

Kindly provide the logic/sample code to implement the same.
The class extending BaseAdapter is working fine.  I need only the Layout related details for displaying the two image on a horizontal manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about having two images in a horizontal `LinearLayout`? Your `res/layout/main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image_1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image_2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</Linearlayout>
```

and then in your java code you can switch out images easily using the `ImageView#setImageFoo` methods:

```
ImageView first = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_1);
first.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_picture);
```

where `my_picture.png` would be an image in your `res/drawables` folder.

Comment: I am using the BaseAdapter due to the reasons:   1> The two images have some functionalities , they can be deleted & the value is stored in the database. Basically , I am displaying a list of 2 items in landscape mode. On each of the images  , I add a textview & a delete icon. Because of some of these features , I am passing the text values , the delete icon through the adapter . So, normal adding 2 ImageViews to my layout file wont work . It should be such that first image is added to the layout by calling the BaseAdapter class & then the next image is added to the existing list similarly.

Comment: I don't think you have to use a list for this. You can just use two custom views. However, if you need to do a horizontal adapter-based view, you can try to use GridView and make sure that it can fit both items in one row.

Comment: Thanks Matthew , I am using GridView . Can you suggest , how to make the GridView layout file that , the first image is positioned 50 dip from left layout margin & the second image is positioned 50 dip from right layout margin ?

Comment: You can measure the screen size and then set your column width and gridview padding accordingly.

Comment: Yep the `GridView` seems to be the only existing class that would give the functionality desired. Alternatively create a custom `View` class that extends `AbsListView` (since this doesn't specify how items should be layed out) and then lay out the items as you choose.

Comment: Regarding the image spacing: just a left and right padding to the GridView (if you want to move the images away from the screen edges).